# What is the best way use link_to in my scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working with rails, So I have got a problem here

```
link_to 'Movie Title', {:action=> 'sort', :checks=>"#{@temp.join('_')}"}, :id => 'title_header'
```

This is my code snippet and on hovering or clicking on this link what I get is,
/movies/sort?checks=G_PG_NC-17

But I need it to be like movies/sort/G_PG_NC-17 , See the difference there is no "checks?" in second url, Anyway I can make that happen with the help of javascript and some changes in routs.rb , but I think there is something else , I can easily get it done.
Your inputs are highly appreciated.

Cheers.
Jossie.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easier way than to edit the `routes.rb` file and add something like:

`match 'movies/sort/:checks`

Answer (score 0):

add this in routes

`get '/movies/sort/:checks' => 'movies#sort', as: :movies_sort_checks`

then

`link_to 'Movie Title', movies_sort_checks_path(@temp.join('_'))`

Answer (score 0):

Finally It is done by myself, Anyway I am quite new to rails, I think other wise I would not have come up with this question.

So this part link_to 'Movie Title', {:action=> 'sort', :checks=>"#{@temp.join('_')}"}, :id => 'title_header'  changes to link_to 'Movie Title',returm_link(@temp), :id => 'title_header'

See now return_link is a helper method.
go to controller and add 
def return_link(kick)
'/'+shot+'/'+kick.join('_')
end
helper_method :stringo

Finally as you expect change routes.rb
match '/sort/:checks', :to => 'movies#sort'

Done everything works as expected, so a custom helper is really helpful here

Cheers .
Jossie.